# How do html wrap text but break words if too long

Tags: html

I have a string that is causing a large gap in my text as it is not wrapping. I'm guessing the default wrapping for Chrome is by word. Any clues on how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use CSS to solve this. Just add word-break to the css of the containing html and select the desired behavior.

```
Syntax
word-break: normal|break-all|keep-all;

Value   Description
normal  Break words according to their usual rules
break-all   Lines may break between any two letters
keep-all    Breaks are prohibited between pairs of letters
```

This answer came from W3Schools http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_word-break.asp